# Can we update Spanish translation in Touch ID pop up?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, touch-id

We need to update Spanish translation in iOS app based on user account setting not based on device settings and We have updated all texts by having two texts with both language in separate class file like below,

```
+(NSString *)cancelText:(NSString*)key {
NSDictionary *txt = @{@"1":@"Cancel",@"2":@"Cancelar"};
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",key]; 
}
```

Now my question is, we have Touch ID integration in our app. I know we can only pass localizedReason and localizedFallbackTitle (for button), Is there any possiblility to change the title "Touch ID for "App name" " and Cancel button in Touch ID pop up. I have attached the screen shot, Please check. Please share your thoughts.

[image: Touch ID Authentication]

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: System dialogs like this will be automatically localised based on the locale the user has selected for their device. You cannot change the button text yourself.

Comment: Ok Thanks! Is there any possibility to set language from code?

Comment: Have a look at `NSLocalizedString` on how to change your labels, etc when the system language changes.